# Beveling from tutorial not working for me, can't find a work around

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, bevel

So I'm just a beginner and I'm just learning some basic modeling, I'm following this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICBP-7x7Chc&index=2&list=PLs2aOcA-EaLNX5j2yxVQhEBpFgD3zDR9P

And at 21:00 he adds 2 loop cuts in the middle of the chest and then adds 2 more edges to the bevel but when I do it you get the following. I've already exhausted my limited knowledge and I just don't know what to do. The only way I can think of to fix it is to manually move and rotate the edges so they line up the way they did in the tutorial I cited earlier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try switching interaction mode to Object mode (undo the operation on the screenshot), select the object, press Ctrl+A > Scale to apply scale to object data. Also as it seems from tutorial you don't need that much beveling, just a tiny bit, roughly 1/20 width of the chest (so make sure to not move your mouse way too away or enter amount from keyboard).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem, I also just showed that much beveling in the image in my question just so you can actually see it. Your advice changed the way it behaved but its still doing the same thing but differently.

Comment: There something is really off on the bottom visible on the first screenshot, there should be clean face loop while it doesn't seem to be. I suggest removing doubles in Edit mode with all selected as already mentioned after you apply scale. If it doesn't help share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some vertices in the middle of the faces of the floor of the chest, inside and out, which are not there in the tutorial. There are edges extending to them from your new edge-loops, and the corners. The floor of the chest should be a plain Ngon. I would go back to before introducing the new edge loops, and check for them.

While you're back there check for other vertices that shouldn't be there.. both ones you can see, and ones you can't. (Right-click to select a vertex, <kbd>G</kbd> to move it, right-click again to drop it back where it came from if it hasn't revealed a duplicate, or otherwise acted strangely.)

In edit mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> -> Edge Menu > 'Remove Doubles' to get rid of coincident extra vertices.

You may have to delete the floor faces altogether and replace them by <kbd>Alt</kbd> - selecting the edges on the perimeters of the new holes, and hitting <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but I started from scratch and it had no problems. I don't see anything different from what I did with my first one.

Infact the only difference comes when I bevel the side of the truck. My second one has disconnected edges and my first one has one edge for each segment of the bevel. But its obviously not what I want since it looks like its inbred.

[image]

[image]